# Reading and writing to an existing file in perl

Tags: perl

I want to read and write to an existing file using perl.

can any one tell me what is the mode that i have to use for such purpose:
I am quite confused by the below modes available.
I tried with `+>` but its not writing to the file.

```
mode operand create truncate 
read     <   
write    >    ✓      ✓ 
append  >>    ✓  

mode       operand create truncate 
read/write  +<   
read/write  +>       ✓      ✓ 
read/append +>>      ✓
```

For eg:
 i have a file like below:

```
one
two 
four
```

i want to insert a  line in between like :

```
one
two
three
four
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at what `perlopentut` has to say about [Mixing Reads and Writes](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlopentut.html#Mixing-Reads-and-Writes). The conclusion is that none of the mixed-mode open modes are ideal, and the in-place edit mode (using `$^I`) is a better solution.

For this particular problem I recommend the [`Tie::File`](https://metacpan.org/module/Tie%3a%3aFile) module, which allows you to treat the file as a simple array.

As an example, to insert the line `three` into your example data, write

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Tie::File;

tie my @file, 'Tie::File', 'myfile.txt' or die $!;

splice @file, 2, 0, 'three';

untie @file or die $!;
```

Comment: This is a nice solution.  The downside, though, is that each insert to the file is made immediately and is quite costly, since the whole file after that point has to be shifted.  If you have to make lots of inserts, look in to the deferred writing feature of Tie::File - https://metacpan.org/module/Tie%3a%3aFile#Deferred-Writing

Comment: The "Mixing Reads and Writes" chapter has been removed in the [perlopentut page](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlopentut). The last version where it appears seems to be v. 5.18.4: https://perldoc.perl.org/5.18.4/perlopentut#Mixing-Reads-and-Writes. But the recommended Tie::File module is part of the standard distribution since Perl 5.8.0.

Answer (score 1):

From [perldoc for `open`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html), you have two immediate problems:

> +< is almost always preferred for read/write updates--the +> mode would clobber the file first.

and

> You can't usually use either read-write mode for updating textfiles,
>   since they have variable-length records.

More generally, you have a design problem in trying to insert data in the middle of the file--text files don't work like that.  The simplest ways to do this are either:

1. Read the whole file into memory, then write the file with modifications
2. Read through the input file line by line, writing the output to another file with modifications.  Then delete the original file and rename the new one to the old name.

1) is the simplest, but 2) would be more memory-efficient if the file is huge.

Edit: there is also [a `-i` switch that allows Perl to edit files in-place](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html).  It does so by implementing 2) for you behind the scenes.  However, I personally would prefer to stick with doing it myself.  This seems more confusing than it's worth.

Answer (score 1):

In-place file insertions can be a bit difficult as data has to be moved. Please see **[dan1111](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1584772/dan1111)**'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12070202/66353) on how to accomplish the objective in an alternative way (which is to be preferred).

However, for the sake of in-place insertions:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $file = 'input';
open my $fh, '+<', $file or die "Failed to open $file: $!";

my $pos, @remaining_lines;
while (<$fh>) {
    if ($pos) {
        push @remaining_lines, $_;
    }
    elsif (m{^two$/$}) {
        $pos = tell;
    }
}

my $word = 'three';
seek $fh, $pos, 0;
print $fh $word, $/, @remaining_lines;
```

Comment: Thanks for a nice illustration of this little-used feature.