# Perl: How to add a line to sorted text file

Tags: perl, file

I want to add a line to the text file in perl which has data in a sorted form. I have seen examples which show how to append data at the end of the file, but since I want the data in a sorted format.

Please guide me how can it be done.

Basically from what I have tried so far : 
(I open a file, grep its content to see if the line which I want to add to the file already exists. If it does than exit else add it to the file (such that the data remains in a sorted format)

```
open(my $FH, $file) or die "Failed to open file $file \n";
@file_data = <$FH>;
close($FH);
my $line = grep (/$string1/, @file_data);
if($line) {
   print "Found\n";
   exit(1);
}
else
{
  #add the line to the file
  print "Not found!\n";
}
```

Comment: for inplace editing in perl pls look at [this][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12070115/reading-and-writing-to-an-existing-file-in-perl

Answer (score 3):

Here's an approach using [Tie::File](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Tie%3a%3aFile) so that you can easily treat the file as an array, and [List::BinarySearch](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?List%3a%3aBinarySearch)'s `bsearch_str_pos` function to quickly find the insert point.  Once you've found the insert point, you check to see if the element at that point is equal to your insert string.  If it's not, `splice` it into the array.  If it is equal, don't splice it in.  And finish up with `untie` so that the file gets closed cleanly.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Tie::File;
use List::BinarySearch qw(bsearch_str_pos);

my $insert_string = 'Whatever!';
my $file          = 'something.txt';

my @array;
tie @array, 'Tie::File', $file or die $!;

my $idx = bsearch_str_pos $insert_string, @array;

splice @array, $idx, 0, $insert_string
    if $array[$idx] ne $insert_string;

untie @array;
```

The `bsearch_str_pos` function from [List::BinarySearch](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?List%3a%3aBinarySearch) is an adaptation of a binary search implementation from [Mastering Algorithms with Perl](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9781565923980.do).  Its convenient characteristic is that if the search string isn't found, it returns the index point where it could be inserted while maintaining the sort order.

Comment: Mr O! Thanks for pointing to your excellent library to be used on ginormous files. One question though: if it - as it seems - almost impossible to implement a b-search, how can we be sure yours is correct?

Comment: Binary search clearly isn't impossible to implement correctly -- it's quite basic. But mistakes happen, and in theory they're found more quickly if lots of people have looked and used the code than if it's a one-off solution used by few.  The source code is publically available and sane bug reports and pull requests are welcome.

Comment: For people looking to actually do ginormous (11gigs, 300m records) files - like me (check here if you want to know what I am doing https://haveibeenpwned.com/Passwords ) the File:tie actually totally fell on its face :( 100% cpu, RAM usage through the roof, swapping like crazy. Killed it before it killed my workstation.

Comment: Disk based binary searches are possible but you have to solve the problem of finding where records start without reading the entire file each time it needs to be searched. Building an index or an index file can be one way.  Or using fixed record sizes.  Or building an index of sorted keys... several ways to solve the problem, but each with their own challenges.

Comment: Right. The records indeed are fixed size (40 Byte SHA1-hex-hash + newlines) and thus my first implementation in python was to just cut the file by its size in bytes in half, then roll back some chars to the next full line and snatch a value. Rinse and repeat. As I'll have to integrate that with native Perl code, I thought I'd try for libs because I have low confidence in what I had cobbled up as a proof of concept ^^ Takes between 20 and 50ms per try. DM me if you want the code (too ugly for github).

Answer (score 1):

Since you have to read the contents of the text file anyway, how about a different approach?

Read the lines in the file one-by-one, comparing against your target string. If you read a line equal to the target string, then you don't have to do anything.

Otherwise, you eventually read a line 'greater' than your current line according to your sort criteria, or you hit the end of the file. In the former case, you just insert the string at that position, and then copy the rest of the lines. In the latter case, you append the string to the end.

If you don't want to do it that way, you can do a binary search in `@file_data` to find the spot to add the line without having to examine all of the entries, then insert it into the array before outputting the array to the file.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple version that reads from stdin (or filename(s) specified on command line) and appends 'string to append' to the output if it's not found in the input.  Outuput is printed on stdout.

```
#! /usr/bin/perl 

$found = 0;
$append='string to append';

while(<>) {
    $found = 1 if (m/$append/o);
    print
}

print "$append\n" unless ($found);;
```

Modifying it to edit a file in-place (with perl -i)  and taking the append string from the command line would be quite simple.

Answer (score 0):

A 'simple' one-liner to insert a line without using any module could be:

```
perl -ni -le '$insert="lemon"; $eq=($insert cmp $_); if ($eq == 0){$found++}elsif($eq==-1 && !$found){print$insert} print'
```

giver a `list.txt` whose context is:

```
ananas
apple
banana
pear
```

the output is:

```
ananas
apple
banana
lemon
pear
```

Comment: This is the best solution, but it could really do with some readability. It doesn't actually have to be a one-liner; you can activate in-place editing mode with the `$^I` global variable.

Answer (score 0):

```
{
  local ($^I, @ARGV) = ("", $file); # Enable in-place editing of $file

  while (<>) {
    # If we found the line exactly, bail out without printing it twice
    last if $_ eq $insert;
    # If we found the place where the line should be, insert it
    if ($_ gt $insert) {
      print $insert;
      print;
      last;
    }
    print;
  }
  # We've passed the insertion point, now output the rest of the file
  print while <>;
}
```

Essentially the same answer as pavel's, except with a lot of readability added. Note that `$insert` should already contain a trailing newline.